# How to put twitter embed script into variable

Tags: jquery, twitter

I trying to embed feed from my twitter into my website and I trying embed code into variable. I want to show feed when I click button, but I have problem with call my variable. Is it possible to put embed script into variable

here my code below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var feed = "<a class='twitter-timeline' data-width='400' data-height='300' href='https://twitter.com/prabowo?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw'>Tweets</a> <script async src='https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' charset='utf-8'></script>";

$(".show-feed").click(function(){
  $(".my-feed").html(feed);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="show-feed">
Show Twitter Feed
</div>

<div class="my-feed">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to append the script and input tags. It might be better to add the script directly and hide the feed div until you click on it. Also look at the jquery getScript function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.setAttribute('src','https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
scriptTag.setAttribute('async','true');
scriptTag.setAttribute('charset','utf-8');
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('data-width', '400');
link.setAttribute('data-height','300');
link.setAttribute('href', 'https://twitter.com/prabowo?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw');
link.textContent = 'Tweets';

  $(".show-feed").click(function(){
    $('.my-feed').append(scriptTag, link);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="show-feed">
Show Twitter Feed
</div>

<div class="my-feed">
</div>
```